# How to add .mdb database into to Visual Studio 2013 published application

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am very new to VS 2013. I am using visual basic. I created a folder named "assets" and placed `mq.mdb` into this folder. Then from Solution Explorer of VS 2013, right clicked on `mq.mdb` and selected include in project. The file is also listed in project properties. My program works in debug and release mode, i.e. it uses mq.mdb file from assets folder.

**But when I publish this and then try to run the app, it throws error for Not valid path.** (please have a look at the attached screenshot)

**Edit 2.**
(Forgot to mention earlier that) I have also set Build Action property of MDB file to Content and the Build. MDB file is also included in the Publish Settings.

[image: screenshot of error]

I even visited the location. It's path is very long, but .mdb file is present there too, but i am still getting errors. I am stuck here for hours.

---

**Edit 1.**

(if it helps in solving query) I am calling MS access database like this -

```
dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
dbSource = "Data Source = " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "assets/mq.mdb;"
dbPassword = "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password;"
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource & dbPassword
con.Open()
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblTest"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "Test")
con.Close()
```

Thanks. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the MDB file in the Solution Explorer and then set its Build Action property to Content and build.  Go to the Publish page of the project properties and click the Application Files button.  You should find that the MDB file is listed as Included in the publish.

When you publish such an app, ClickOnce detects that the MDB file is a data file and installs it in a specific folder dedicated to data files.  The absolute path of that folder is not revealed to you but you don't need it.  You use the `|DataDirectory|` place-holder in your connection string to refer to it and it gets resolved at run time.  You can change your code to:

```
dbSource = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|\mq.mdb;"
```

There's really no need to use those three separate variables for the connection string because you can use a single string literal but, if you really want to set each value separately, I suggest that you use a connection string builder, e.g.

```
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder

builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
builder.DataSource = "|DataDirectory|\mq.mdb"
builder.Add("Jet OLEDB:Database Password", "password")

Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
```

Comment: I had already set its Build Action property to Content and yes it's included in the publish too.(sorry i forgot to mention that in question earlier). The error displayed in the screenshot is after doing all of this. And I also confirmed that .mdb file is present in the mentioned path.

Comment: Thanks for updated answer. Earlier my path to data files was not correct (as evident, I was using `assets` folder instead of `|DataDirectory|`). Now it works for ClickOnce. But meanwhile, I was using InstallShield for making SingleImage setup file. Now it seems, InstallShield does NOT understand `|DataDirectory|` and InstallShield created setup search for MDB file in root, instead of its dedicated `Database[DATABASEDIR]` folder. Is there any way to resolve this, so that in case of revision, I wont have to do changes for both?

Comment: The `|DataDirectory|` place-holder is resolved at run time. For a ClickOnce deployed app, it resolves to a special ClickOnce-managed folder, for ASP.NET apps it resolves to the App_Data folder and for other Windows apps it resolves to the program folder. You can change that in code via the current `AppDomain`. You can also store your connection string in the config file and then modify it during or after deployment. For instance, for a non-ClickOnce Windows app, "|DataDirectory|\assets" will resolve to the 'assets' folder under the program folder.

Comment: Thanks. Now I got it, how does `|DataDirectory|` behave. But I didn't get your solution for it ("change that in code via the current AppDomain. You can also store your connection string in the config file and then modify it during or after deployment"). It would be very helpful for me if you could please explain it through a demo code. Sorry for asking too much, but being a medical doctor, I dont have much knowledge of VS and I cant learn it in a proper way. All i can do is to search stackoverflow and google. Thanks.